# Add/remove class from element depending on whether another element has the class

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I have 4 boxes and the user needs to select one.

I want to apply an active class to the box that the user has clicked. But if the user clicks another box, I want to remove the class from the first clicked box and add it to the second clicked box.

The below code doesn't work - anyone know why? Even if the below code ran the way I would expect it to, it still wouldn't be checking the other boxes around it to see if they have the active class before adding/removing.

html:

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

css:

```
.box {
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 30px 50px;
}

.active {
  outline: solid 5px aqua;
}
```

js:

```
var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box');

for(var i = 0; i < box.length; i++){
  box[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        if(box[i].classList.contains('active')){
      box[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
    else {
      box[i].classList.add('active');
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to remove the `active` class for all elements and then use `this.classList.add('active')` after the loop, since you only would like to set the `active` class on the currently clicked element:

```
for(var i = 0; i < box.length; i++){
  box[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    // remove active class for all elements
    for(var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
       box[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
    // add active to clicked element
    this.classList.add('active');
  });
}
```

Comment: It's better to answer in pure Javascript as compare to relying on jQuery all the time.

Comment: @YourFriend - Yes, I agree.

Comment: Thanks man - I'm new to js, and sat here racking my brain for ages trying to figure out how to do this and seeing your solution it was one of those 'Why didn't I think of that?' moments. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

If you can use jquery, this works:

```js
$('.box').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('.box').not(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.box {
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 30px 50px;
}
.active {
  outline: solid 5px aqua;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$(".box").on("click", function() {
    $(".box").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

It's not pure javascript but should do what you want

Comment: He is **not** using jquery.